# On saving other files my nuxt.config.js is being automatically updated ! Why?

Tags: javascript, webpack, nuxt.js

every time when I'm changing any files of my project ,it's automatically update **nuxt.config.js**.it's taking longer then usual to Build my app. it's so frustrating..............

[Hot Reload Nuxt-Terminal image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFIae.png)

Comment: What is actually updated there? Do you have a global linter? Can you show us the `nuxt.config.js` file? :)

Comment: There seems to be some linter for sure, that is doing the same for you. Please be exact and let us know what exactly is being changed. :)